# How to animate slider elements if they are not positioned absolutely?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create an animated slider for my website and I'm using floats and margins to position the elements of the slider, I was searching for anything I can integrate into my slider that will animate the elements, and I found that I need to use CSS3 transitions and those elements need to be positioned absolutely inside their parent, and this is the issue.
I don't want to position the elements absolutely because of the way I have them positioned now   and the elements have a variable size.

So how can I animate or transition these elements without using position absolute ?
I want to animate each element differently with different durations and directions.

and thanks.

UPADTE: I'm using Flexslider by WooThemes

Comment: Provide example of your markup http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You could code your logic using margin property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ad through javascript to the CSS the

```
'+=10px' or '-=10px'
```

so adds or decreases the value of the elemnt you want to animate without having to state the exact amount of result. Hope it helps

EDIT

You could also use this in your @keyframes without any javascript

Comment: what do you mean by '+=10px' or '-=10px' ?
and will keyframes work without positioning the elements absolutely ?

Comment: i mean you increment or decrease the number the elemnt already have, and yes, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use [`transform: translate(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform). Transform is independent from the surrounding markup/styles (e.g. `position: absolute`) and hardware accelerated even on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can modify any property of a DOM element with [.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/), that means you can animate the element's margins and paddings keeping their relative position.